Shifted Borel set
Let $A$ be bounded Borel subset of the real line with $\lambda(A)>0$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. How does one show that $f(x)=\lambda(A \cap (x+A)$ is continuous in $x$? My attempt:
Let $(x_n)$ be any sequence converging to $x$, then it suffices to show $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. In particular, if one shows $\mathbb{1}_{A \cap (x_n+A)}$ converges to $\mathbb{1}_{A \cap (x+A)}$ then by dominating convergence we are done. Unfortunately, if $x$ is an isolated point this does not seem work.
Is it possible to fix this argument? Much appreciated.

I think your argument can be fixed. Basically, you can show that when $A$ is an open set, we do have the convergence you need. Then you can argue about the fact that every Borel set can be approximated by an open set.

The method suggest by @Izaak is perhaps more useful to think through than my answer, as this is a very common way of proving statements in measure theory.

Here's a different approach: Using the fact that for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, the convolution $(f*g)(x)$ is a continuous function of $x$ (a proof is sketched here), we see that $$f(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_{A\cap(x+A)}(t)dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\chi_A(t)\chi_{-A}(x-t)dt=(\chi_A*\chi_{-A})(x).$$ Since $A$ is bounded and Borel, $\chi_A, \chi_{-A}\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) $ and thus $f$ is continuous as desired.

Nice approach. But the statement you link seems unrelated - did you mean something like this?

Yes, you're totally right, the assumption that one of the functions is in $L^\infty$ is necessary. I will update.
